# Covering if-else conditions in a Testclass

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm having a save method with several Conditions in it.Here is my apex class

```
invoiceset = [select SiteUrl__c, Prefix__c,Seperator__c,Seperator1__c,DateValue__c,DateValue1__c,Date_Format__c,Incrementer__c,Counter_Val1__c,counter__c from Invoice_setting__c limit 1];

      if(invoiceSet[0].DateValue__c == 'Date' && invoiceSet[0].DateValue1__c == 'Date'){
        if(invoiceSet[0].Date_Format__c == 'dd-mm-yyyy'){
             datenow = DateTime.now().format('dd-MM-yyyy');          
        }else if(invoiceSet[0].Date_Format__c == 'MM-dd-yyyy'){
             datenow = DateTime.now().format('MM-dd-yyyy');           
         }else if(invoiceSet[0].Date_Format__c == 'dd/MM/yyyy'){
             datenow = DateTime.now().format('dd/MM/yyyy');
         }else if(invoiceSet[0].Date_Format__c == 'mm/dd/yyyy'){
             datenow = DateTime.now().format('mm/dd/yyyy');
         }else if(invoiceSet[0].Date_Format__c == 'yy'){
             datenow = DateTime.now().format('yy');
         }else if(invoiceSet[0].Date_Format__c == 'yyyy'){
             datenow = DateTime.now().format('yyyy');
         }
          prefixName = invoiceset[0].prefix__c + invoiceSet[0].seperator__c + datenow + invoiceset[0].Seperator1__c + datenow; 
     }

    else if(invoiceSet[0].DateValue__c == 'Counter' && invoiceSet[0].DateValue1__c == 'Counter'){
      if(invoiceSet[0].counter_val1__c == null){
         invoiceSet[0].Counter_Val1__c = invoiceset[0].Counter__c;
       }else if(invoiceSet[0].Counter_Val1__c == invoiceset[0].Counter__c){
           intt = integer.valueof(invoiceSet[0].Counter__c) + integer.valueOf(invoiceSet[0].Incrementer__c) ;
           invoiceSet[0].Counter_Val1__c = string.valueOf(intt) ;
       }else {
            intt = integer.valueof(invoiceSet[0].Counter_Val1__c) + integer.valueOf(invoiceSet[0].Incrementer__c) ;
           invoiceSet[0].Counter_Val1__c = string.valueOf(intt) ;
       }
       update invoiceset;
        prefixName = invoiceset[0].prefix__c + invoiceSet[0].seperator__c + invoiceSet[0].Counter_Val1__c + invoiceset[0].Seperator1__c +invoiceset[0].Counter_Val1__c; 
     } && so on........
```

Inorder to cover all this conditions should I write those many methods or any other easy way?

Here is my Test Code

```
public static testmethod void test(){
   invoice_setting__c setng = new invoice_setting__c(Name='Invoice Settings',SiteUrl__c='www.google.com',Prefix__c='Test',Seperator__c = '-',dateValue__c = 'Date',Seperator1__c = '/',dateValue1__c = 'Date',date_format__c='dd-mm-yyyy');
    insert setng;
}
public static testmethod void test1(){
    invoice_setting__c setng1 = new invoice_setting__c(Name='Invoice Settings',Prefix__c='Test',Seperator__c = '-',dateValue__c = 'Counter',Seperator1__c = '/',Counter_Val1__c=null,dateValue1__c = 'Counter',date_format__c='dd-mm-yyyy',Incrementer__c='10');
    insert setng1;
} & so on......
```

Any Suggestions for this please

Comment: Can you simplify the first set of ifs by saying `datenow = DateTime.now().format(invoiceSet[0].Date_Format__c);`?

Answer (score 5):

**Short Answer**

Yes, you should have a test for each case.

**Long Answer**

Why would you want one test per if? So that you *know* your code is handling the various possibilities correctly. What happens if Date_Format__c somehow gets a value of `MM/yyyy`? What if a field has an unexpected value? The purpose of these test cases is to verify functionality and yes, the number of tests will grow with [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity); the more paths your code has, the harder it is to test. And of course sufficiently complex code will eventually become impossible or unfeasible to fully test, so we do our best.

My general goals are:

1. Test the common use cases
2. Test corner cases that can cause problems (e.g. division by zero)
3. Test for previously fixed bugs